# how to draw a vertical scale bar with css

Tags: css

i want to draw a vertical scale bar with css for my project. please help me. here u can see the image.

http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=vertical+scale+bar&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1024&bih=578&tbm=isch&tbnid=FJiiXsutIEBcKM:&imgrefurl=http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/gauge-linear-scale-bar-v.html&docid=3x5FkAAE7L13NM&w=150&h=500&ei=EFOFTu2HPMjxrQei8Y3tAw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=236&vpy=43&dur=1&hovh=400&hovw=120&tx=78&ty=217&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=38&start=0&ndsp=18&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0

like above diagram i have to draw with css and html.

Comment: i did with progress bar but my manager is asking scale also. i tried in google i didn't get the examples for vertical scale bar. so i need help to draw like the above image.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this I suppose. Just need to add in some scale marks. Can set the height of the inner bar dynamically with javascript / or server side output.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="therm">
        <div id="inner">
            <div id="bar">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#container{
    width:60px;
    height: 350px;
}

#therm{
    background-color: green;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    position: relative;
}

#inner{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#bar{
    background-color: black;
    width: 15px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUeCn/

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, that shows scale and fills the scale bar with a nice gradient color

```
<div id="scale">
    200 -<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    175 -<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    150 -<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    125 -<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    100 -<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    75 -<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    .<br />
    50 -<br />
<div>
<div id="outer">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
#scale {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    text-align: right;
}
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0f0), to(#fa0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0f0,  #fa0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0f0', endColorstr='#fa0');
}

#outer > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/pUMQ5/)**